# Excel Variation on "First Monday" formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

EDITED:

When I first posted this question I asked for a formula to solve one condition, but then realized that it actually has *two* conditions.

Given a particular date:

1. Return the first Monday of that month, which may actually the *last* Monday of the *previous* month. (This occurs when the actual first Monday falls on the 7th.)
2. If the given date is *before* the first Monday of that month (e.g. 8/1/19, which was a Wednesday), return the first Monday of the *previous* month (in this case, 7/1/19).

Ron's formula:

```
=A1-DAY(A1)+7-WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1)-2)
```

...fit the first condition, and it's short and elegant. Maybe it can be adjusted to fit the second.

Comment: could you share some sample data showing where went wrong and what should be the expected output?

Comment: Your conditions are not mutually exclusive unless the second condition will always take precedence over the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the problem a bit differently.  This seems to work:

```
=A1-DAY(A1)+7-WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1)-2)
```

It is returning the Monday prior to the 7th of the Month.

**EDIT**

I must assume that your 2nd condition takes precedence over the first, else it would never apply.

That being the case

- use an `IF` function to test if the given `DAY` is **less than** the given `WEEKDAY` using the option for the week start being on **Monday**.
- if such is the case, then replace `A1` with `EDATE(A1,-1)` in the formula.

---

```
=IF(DAY(A1)<WEEKDAY(A1,2),EDATE(A1,-1)-DAY(EDATE(A1,-1))+7-WEEKDAY(EDATE(A1,-1)-DAY(EDATE(A1,-1))-2),A1-DAY(A1)+7-WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1)-2))
```

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson Just use an `IF` to test, and then replace `A1` with `EDATE(A1,-1)`

Comment: We have a winner!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Just by checking if 1st of the Month is a Tuesday you can then subtract 1, otherwise subtract the Weekday as you already have done.

```
=DATE(YEAR(H20),MONTH(H20),1)+IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(H20),MONTH(H20),1),1)=3,-1,CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(H20),MONTH(H20),1)),1,0,6,5,4,3,2))
```

This also does the same with less characters;

```
=EOMONTH(H20,-1)+IF(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(H20,-1)+1,12)=1,0,9-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(H20,-1)+1,11))
```